# How to conditionally disable the evaluation of certain item template in asp.net list view?

Tags: asp.net

A few of my database table doesn't have ClassID whereas certain has. How can I disable the evaluation here?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="FnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="RoleIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoleName") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ClassIDlabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="GenderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' />
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make sure all your queries return the same values if you are always binding them to a GridView in the same way.

So if a table does not have the column `ClassID`, just add it in the query itself.

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, RoleName, Gender, 0 AS ClassID, 'or as string' AS ClassIDstr FROM table
```